# PHP 5.3.0 USE keyword -- how to backport in 5.2?

Tags: php

I have some code that has been written in for php 5.3.0 using the USE function within PHP

can someone help me change this to work for 5.2.9?

```
$available  = array_filter($objects, function ($object) use ($week) { 
    return !in_array($object, $week);
});
```

thanks for the help

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier-should-a-sane-programmer-use

Comment: You probably shouldn't call `use()` a function, as its a little confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not nice, but this would be an equivalent implementation.

```
class MyWeekFilter {
    protected $_week;

    public function __construct($week) {
        $this->_week = $week;
    }

    public function filter($object) {
        return !in_array($object, $this->_week);
    }
}

$filter    = new MyWeekFilter($week);
$available = array_filter($objects, array($filter, 'filter'));
```

Comment: Well played, sir, well played. You just saved my life tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any difference between author's code

```
$available = array_filter($objects, function ($object) use ($week) { 
    return !in_array($object, $week);
});
```

and

```
$available = array_diff($objects, $week);
```

?

Comment: The author may have cut down the problem space to a simple example that is easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
$available  = array_filter($objects, create_function('$object', '
    $week = '.var_export($week,true).';
    return !in_array($object, $week);
'));
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
$week = array(...); // defined and instantiated before...

function callback($object) {
    return !in_array($object, $week);
}
$available  = array_filter($objects, "callback");
```

Comment: This won't work. `$week` is a global variable, which must be *imported* into the function scope: `function callback($object) { global $week; return !in_array($object, $week); }`

Comment: `$week` is not available in callback unless pulled in using `global`

Comment: True. Sorry for missing this.