# Confusion with 'use' identifier in PHP closures

Tags: php, closures

I'm a little confused with PHP closures. Can someone clear this up for me:

```
// Sample PHP closure
my_method(function($apples) use ($oranges) {
    // Do something here
});
```

What's the difference between `$apples` and `$oranges` and when should I be using each?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In PHP 5.3.0, what is the function "use" identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$apples` will take on the value that is passed to the function when it is called, e.g.

```
function my_method($callback) {
    // inside the callback, $apples will have the value "foo"
    $callback('foo'); 
}
```

`$oranges` will refer to the value of the variable `$oranges` which exists in the scope where you defined the closure. E.g.:

```
$oranges = 'bar';

my_method(function($apples) use ($oranges) {
    // $oranges will be "bar"
    // $apples will be "foo" (assuming the previous example)
});
```

The differences is that `$oranges` is bound when the function is **defined** and `$apples` is bound when the function is **called**.

---

Closures let you access variables defined outside of the function, but you have to explicitly tell PHP which variables should be accessible. This is similar (but not equivalent!) to using the `global` keyword if the variable is defined in global scope:

```
$oranges = 'bar';

my_method(function($apples) {
    global $oranges;
    // $oranges will be "bar"
    // $apples will be "foo" (assuming the previous example)
});
```

The differences between using closures and `global`:

- You can bind *local* variables to closures, `global` only works with global variables.
- Closures bind the *value* of the variable at the time the closure was **defined**. Changes to the variables after the function was defined does not effect it.
  On the other hand, if you use `global`, you will receive the value the variable has at the moment when the function is **called**.

  Example:

  ```
  $foo = 'bar';
  $closure = function() use ($foo) { 
      echo $foo; 
  };
  $global = function() {
      global $foo;
      echo $foo;
  };

  $foo = 42;
  $closure(); // echos "bar"
  $global(); // echos 42
  ```

Comment: How is it different from using `global` because that's the first thing which came to mind.

Comment: @enchance: Because `use` can access variables in a local scope.  When you do `use ($oranges)`, `$oranges` doesn't need to be global like it does when you do `global $oranges;`.

Comment: `global` **is not** equivalent of `use` since `global` will refer to pure global context (also represented by `$GLOBALS`) while `use` will pass only current, local context.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: Exactly, that's why I said it is not equivalent.

Comment: @enchance: Added an explanation.

Comment: when `$foo` gets changed inside the `function()` it does not affect the value `$foo` has outside of it right?

Comment: But passing by reference is possible? `function() use (&$foo) { }` ?

Comment: @FelixKling: I see, so for closures having a `use` relies on *when* the closure was declared. That's a huge difference from `global`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: It seems so. And assigning a value seems to work as expected.

Comment: @enchance: Sometimes you cannot control *when* and *how* a function is called, e.g. when you pass it as callback to some third party code. You might still need access to value defined outside of the function, and that's what closures solve. Does that help?

Comment: I am confused why did you commented on [What use keyword do in closures in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478596/what-use-keyword-do-in-closures-in-php) as a duplicate (possible duplicate of [In Php 5.3.0 what is the Function "Use" Identifier ? Should a sane programmer use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier) – Felix Kling May 7 '12 at 8:00), but answered this one a few months later!

Comment: @Trix I honestly don't remember why I did that, sorry. It was more than four years ago.

Answer (score 3):

`$apples` is passed as an argument to `my_method`, and `$oranges` is injected inside.