# How to create a new key and store array values in a multidimensional way PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have data here: First, the result of my first function named getsiteaccounts()

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 2
        [AID] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 2
        [AID] => 3
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 6
        [AID] => 4
    )
```

And the result of my second function named bindGHComponentsToSites()

```
   Array
  ( 
  [2] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 2
        [Balance] => 19000.00
        [MinBalance] => 100000.00
        [MaxBalance] => 1000000.00
        [OwnerAID] => 5
        [GroupID] => 1
        [Deposit] => 1500
        [Reload] => 1000
        [Redemption] => 1000
    )

)
```

Then, add the key of [CorpAID] pointing to the list of OwnerAID. BY the way, OwnerAID and AID are the same. As you can see SiteID => 2 owned by two OwnerAID =>  5 and 3. Here's should be the result:

```
   Array([0])=> Array (
        [SiteID] => 2
        [Balance] => 19000.00
        [MinBalance] => 100000.00
        [MaxBalance] => 1000000.00
        [OwnerAID] => 5
        [GroupID] => 1
        [Deposit] => 1500
        [Reload] => 1000
        [Redemption] => 1000
        [CorpAID] => Array(
                   [0] => 5
                   [1] => 3
        )
      )
  )
```

The SiteID => 6 should not be print since it only owned by one AID. Is it possible to make it? Please guide me in proper way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can we see the relevant code? :-)

Comment: @ thedom, what relevant code do you want? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a couple of `foreach` loops to do what you need:

```
<?php

$siteAccounts = array(
  array('SiteID'=>2, 'AID'=>5),
  array('SiteID' => 2, 'AID' => 3),
  array('SiteID' => 6, 'AID' => 4)
);

$componentsToSites = array(array(
  'SiteID' => 2,
  'Balance' => 19000.00,
  'MinBalance' => 100000.00,
  'MaxBalance' => 1000000.00,
  'OwnerAID' => 5,
  'GroupID' => 1,
  'Deposit' => 1500,
  'Reload' => 1000,
  'Redemption' => 1000
));

foreach ($componentsToSites as &$site) {
  $aids = array();
  foreach ($siteAccounts as $acct) {
      if ($acct['SiteID'] === $site['SiteID'])
        $aids[] = $acct['AID'];
  }
  $site['CorpAID'] = $aids;
}

print_r($componentsToSites);
```

***Edit:***

My original answer used [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) rather than `foreach`, but due to compatibility issues I switched it. Here is the original code snippet for using `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($componentsToSites, function (&$site) use ($siteAccounts) {
  $aids = array();
  array_walk($siteAccounts, function ($acct) use ($site, &$aids) {
      if ($acct['SiteID'] === $site['SiteID'])
        $aids[] = $acct['AID'];
  });
  $site['CorpAID'] = $aids;
});
```

Comment: If you're not sure what the `use` keyword does then you might want to check this post for details: [In Php 5.3.0 what is the Function "Use" Identifier?...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier-should-a-sane-programmer-us)

Comment: @ DaoWen, there's an error within array_walk, kindly review those brackets and parethesis. Thank you

Comment: @Mic - There is no error on my end. Are you using PHP4 or PHP5? The anonymous functions might need to be refactored out into named functions in PHP4 to get this to work.

Comment: @ DaoWen, Im using the netbeans, I guess it supports PHP 5, am I lost of answer?

Comment: @Mic - Try running this: `echo phpversion();`. Mine gives `5.3.8`.

Comment: @ DaoWen, here's the result of echo, 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17

Comment: @Mic - Closures have been supported since 5.3.0, so I don't see what the issue is. Try pasting my code above into its own file and running it in the terminal with the php command. It might also help if you post your full error message at the bottom of your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15454/discussion-between-mic-and-daowen)

Comment: @ DaoWen, I move our conversation at the chat. Pls response. Thank you.

Comment: @Mic - I've posted a new version using `foreach` instead of `array_map`. This should work even in much older versions of PHP. Let me know if there are still issues and we can chat.

Comment: @ DaoWen, Ok I'll try it.Pls hold on.