# zf2 - join using a using Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

Tags: zend-framework2, tablegateway

I want to do a simple join using zf2 selecting fields from the first and second table, but I get an error ('Statement could not be executed') when I try to put an array of fields into the columns method.

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
        $select->columns();// ->with params gives an 'Statement could not be executed'
        $select->join(array('t2' => 'categories'), 'table1.idCategory = t2.id');
        $select->order('dateTime DESC')->limit(100);
    });  
...
}
```

Comment: You can find the answer here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354802/tablegateway-with-multiple-from-tables/14371056#14371056

Comment: Can you show an example you are using when it return the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure the dateTime/id fields are in the column list you provide.

If you dump out the exception ($e->getTraceAsString()) you will get some more information about what is causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

Either comment this statement **Or** add atleast one valid 'column' name in array (table column/field name).

```
$select->columns(array('column_one', 'column_two', 'column_N'));
```

A blank `$select->columns();` statement generates sql query something like `SELECT FROM table_name` which results in error.

When you comment this statement, it generates sql query like `SELECT * FROM table_name`
and if you pass column names, asterisk replaced by them.