# Access in view to join data

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm currently working on a Zend 2 project and I have some problems to access the data of a join in the view.

So first, I created my function to get data in my AlbumTable:

```
public function getAllAlbum()
{
    $select = new Select();
    $select->from('album')
            ->join('singer', 'singer.id = album.id')
            ->order('album.id');

    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectwith($select);
    $resultSet->buffer();
    return $resultSet;
}
```

This function give me all datas I wanted. But now in the view, I want to access to there data. I tried a lot of thing like : `->id_album->singer.name`, `->id_album->singer['name']`, `->singer.name` , `->singer['name']` but nothing worked.

**EDIT :**

my controller :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $album = $this->getAlbumTable()->getAllAlbum();

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'listAlbum' => $album
    ));
}
```

And the view :

```
<?
foreach ($this->listAlbum as $param)
{?>
    <tr class="tab_line">
        <td style="width:30%;">
            <a><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($param->name);?></a>
        </td>
        <td style="width:30%;">
            <a><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($param->id_album->nom);?></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?}?>
```

var_dump $album:

```
object(Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet)#420 (8) { 
["allowedReturnTypes":protected]=> array(2) { 
  [0]=> string(11) "arrayobject" 
  [1]=> string(5) "array" } 
    ["arrayObjectPrototype":protected]=> object(Check\Model\Album)#405 (4) {
    ["inputFilter":protected]=> NULL ["id"]=> NULL ["name"]=> NULL 
    ["id_singer"]=> NULL } ["returnType":protected]=> string(11) "arrayobject" 
    ["buffer":protected]=> array(0) { } ["count":protected]=> int(1) 
    ["dataSource":protected]=> object(Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result)#419 (8) { 
    ["statementMode":protected]=> string(7) "forward" 
    ["resource":protected]=> object(PDOStatement)#411 (1) { 
    ["queryString"]=> string(127) "SELECT `album`.*, `singer`.* FROM `album` INNER JOIN `singer` ON `singer`.`id` = `album`.`id` ORDER BY `album`.`id` ASC" } 
    ["options":protected]=> NULL ["currentComplete":protected]=> bool(true)
    ["currentData":protected]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["name"]=> string(9) "Test" ["id_singer"]=> string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=> string(5) "Test2" } ["position":protected]=> int(0) 
    ["generatedValue":protected]=> string(1) "0" ["rowCount":protected]=> int(1) } 
    ["fieldCount":protected]=> int(5) ["position":protected]=> int(0) }
```

Thanks per advance

PokeRwOw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what I wanted. If you want to make a join with Zend 2.0 and object you need to do something like this (in my case) :

```
public function getAllAlbum()
{
    $select = new Select();
    $select->from('album')
        ->join('singer', 'singer.id = album.id')
        ->order('album.id');

    $statement = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $resultSet = $statement->execute();
    $resultSet->buffer();
    return $resultSet;
}
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25983788/3752471

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
   `return new ViewModel(array(
         'albums' => $resultSet,
     ));`
```

in your function 'getAllAlbum' instead of just return $resultSet

Then you loop the albums with foreach like this :

`foreach($albums as $album){ echo $album['title']; }`

**Edit 1**

You can change :

```
`->join('singer', 'singer.id = album.id')'`
```

To :

```
`->join('singer', 'singer.id = album.id', array(singer_name, whateveryouwant))`
```

To select only field you want

Then you can use `$album = $album->toArray();` To convert object into array

And in the view use : 
`foreach($album as $alb){ echo $alb['singer_name']; }`

Comment: Already doing this, I edit my post. I just want to access to the join data only, because in the view I have '$param->id_album->nom' but It's not working

Comment: Can you show us the value of `$album` ? what kind of data is ?

Comment: I added the var_dump of $abum. Strangely I can access to singer->name with $param->name but now I can't access to album->name

Comment: As you can see in the var_dump, the problem isn't coming from the request to db because I have all datas ({ ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(9) "Test" ["id_singer"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(5) "Test2" }).  But I don't know how to access to the variable name coming from the join... I tried your solution anyway and Its does not working

Comment: I come back on your solution, after $album->toArray(); in my controller, It's return me that : **array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["inputFilter"]=> NULL ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(9) "test" ["id_singer"]=> string(1) "2" } } **So I haven't got the singer's name but I added array(singer_name, whateveryouwant) in my model

Comment: No, I debugged the code. The request to db is right (I tested in mysql directly) So the problem is always the same, I can't access to singer_name in the view...