# Zend 2 module.config with constraints with model/controller not retrieveing record

Tags: zend-framework2

I am learning Zend 2 and have an issue i cannot seem to get around. Im sure it is something simple but i cannot pinpoint it. What i am trying to do is list records by state_id and also view a record from the list. Showing only one of the views. When i bring up /Blog/view/1 I get a message that says: Could not find row 0. This shows up with the current link and if i take the /1 off. So it is not even looking at the record number. I suspect it may be in routing but not sure. thanks 
This is what i have:

```
Module.config
'router' => array(
  'routes' => array(      
      'blog' => array(        
        'type'    => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/Blog',
            'defaults' => array (
              'module'     => 'Blog',
              'controller' => 'BlogController',
              'action'     => 'index',
            ), // defaults end 
        ), // options end           
        'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'list' => array(
                    'type'    => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/list[/:state_id]',
                        'defaults' => array (
                            'action'     => 'list',
                        ), //defaults end
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'state_id'     => '[0-9]+',
                        ) // constraints end
                    ), // options end
                ), // view end
                'view' => array(
                    'type'    => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/view[/:post_id]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action'     => 'view',
                        ), // defaults end
                        'constraints' => array(
                        'post_id'     => '[0-9]+',
                        ) // constraints end
                    ), // options end
                ),  // post end 
            ) // child route end            
        ), // blog end
    ) // routes end       
) // router end

); // return array end
```

Model:PostTable.php

```
 public function getPosts($post_id)
 {
   $post_id  = (int) $post_id;
   $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('post_id' => $post_id));
   $row = $rowset->current();
   if (!$row) {
       throw new \Exception("Could not find row $post_id");
   }
   return $row;
 }
```

View:

```
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
<table class="table">
<tr>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>View</th>
   <th>Comments</th>
   <th>Post Date</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($list as $posts) : ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($posts->post_title);?></td>
  <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($posts->num_views);?></td>
  <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($posts->num_comments);?></td>
  <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($posts->post_date);?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Edit: 06/06/2016 Added View Action.

```
 public function viewAction()
 {
    return new ViewModel(array(
     'list' => $this->getPostsTable()->getPosts(),
    )); 
 }
```

Also here is the getPostTable Action:

```
 public function getPostsTable()
 {   
     if (!$this->postsTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->postsTable = $sm->get('Blog\Model\PostsTable');
     }
     return $this->postsTable;
 }
```

Comment: Would you show me the `viewAction()` please?

Comment: @J.Sajeeb Added view Action. This is taken from the Album tutorial for zend 2. It shows what you the getAlbum in the model but does not show how to retrieve it in the controller or what the view would actually look like. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the post ID into the `getPosts()` method in the controller. The following is according to your `PostTable`'s `getPosts()` method.

```
public function viewAction()
{

    // Get the post ID from the route, /Blog/view/1
    $post_id = $this->params()->fromRoute('post_id');

    $list = $this->getPostsTable()->getPosts($post_id);

    $view = new ViewModel(array(
        'list' => $list,
    ));

    return $view;
}
```

Comment: That works! How do you get it to fetch multiple rows with the same Id? For instance if i wanted to pull all records with state_id. This would not be the row or record. The above works for the single record for the view of the page. Now i need to pull all records from that state. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, you need to create another method or modify `PostTable`'s `getPosts()` method. This method returns current post/item by this line of code `$row = $rowset->current();`. You can pull all the records, for `state_id`, for example, by commenting out this line of code and total `if (!$row)` statement and returning `return $rowset;` instead of `return $row;`!

Comment: I also posted another issue i am having under a different blog. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813668/left-join-in-zf2-using-tablegateway