# Zend Framework 2: LEFT JOIN issue

Tags: mysql, join, zend-framework2

```
public function getInterests($userID) {
    $result = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($userID) {
                $select->join('interests', 'users_interests.interest_id = interests.interest_id', array('*'), 'left');
                $where = new Where();
                $where->equalTo('user_id', $userID);
                $select->where($where);
            });

    return $result;
}
```

Here is my method. It simply selects all records from users_interests with user_id = $userID and joins the 'interests' table. So far, so good, but when trying to display the fetched results, the fields from the joined table just do not exist. Here is the dump of the $result:

```
Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet Object
(
[allowedReturnTypes:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => arrayobject
        [1] => array
    )

[arrayObjectPrototype:protected] => Object\Model\UsersInterests Object
    (
        [settings_id] => 
        [user_id] => 
        [interest_id] => 
    )

[returnType:protected] => arrayobject
[buffer:protected] => 
[count:protected] => 2
[dataSource:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result Object
    (
        [statementMode:protected] => forward
        [resource:protected] => PDOStatement Object
            (
                [queryString] => SELECT `users_interests`.*, `interests`.* FROM `users_interests` LEFT JOIN `interests` ON `users_interests`.`interest_id` = `interests`.`interest_id` WHERE `user_id` = :where1
            )

        [options:protected] => 
        [currentComplete:protected] => 
        [currentData:protected] => 
        [position:protected] => -1
        [generatedValue:protected] => 0
        [rowCount:protected] => 2
    )

[fieldCount:protected] => 6
[position:protected] => 
)
```

I badly need help on this because I am supposed to finish my project until Sunday. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to apply left join. $select::JOIN_LEFT instead of 'left'.

```
public function getInterests($userID) {
    $result = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($userID) {
        $select->join('interests', 'users_interests.interest_id = interests.interest_id', array('*'), $select::JOIN_LEFT);
        $where = new Where();
        $where->equalTo('user_id', $userID);
        $select->where($where);
    });

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a problem in the WHERE clause of the join. This also shows in the error here:

```
 [queryString] => SELECT `users_interests`.*, `interests`.* FROM `users_interests` LEFT JOIN  .
 `interests` ON `users_interests`.`interest_id` = `interests`.`interest_id` 
 WHERE `user_id` = :where1
```

Try this:

```
$select->from($this->table)
       ->join('interests', 'users_interests.interest_id = interests.interest_id',
         array('*'), 'left');   
$where = new  Where();
$where->equalTo('user_id', $userID) ;
$select->where($where);
```

I can not follow your code completely, like here:

```
$this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($userID) {
```

But, here is a [***very nice article***](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/zend-framework-2-zenddbsql-join-tables/) on this. I think, you can simplify your code a little.

Comment: The problem remains the same after I edited the query. Please check the first post.

Comment: I read the article but I stil can't get the idea how to join a table in a tableGateway select query. And I also can't understand why my query doesn't work as expected. May you please try to rewrite the query above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you iterated over the resultset? You can see there's two matching rows:

```
[rowCount:protected] => 2
```

You have a ResultSet object, but it will not load any of the rows until requested, they are "lazy loaded" when you iterate over the object.

You can force the resultset to get them all for you:

```
var_dump($resultSet->toArray()); // force load all rows
```

or iterate over the ResultSet:

```
foreach($resultset as $row) {
    var_dump($row); // each row loaded on request
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written about this before and maybe it will help you as well.
[TableGateway with multiple FROM tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354802/tablegateway-with-multiple-from-tables/14371056#14371056)