# Cross Database in ZF2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

how to join two tables from different databases using zf2?
I would like to write the following query.

```
SELECT db1.table1.*, db2.table2.* FROM db1.table1
INNER JOIN db2.table2 ON db2.table2.field1 = db1.table1.field1
```

Please give some example?

Comment: You can find the answer here too -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354802/tablegateway-with-multiple-from-tables/14371056#14371056

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the syntax but it's basically something like this:

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
$select = $db->select()
             ->from( array( 'table1' => 'db1.table1' ), array( 'table1.*','table2.*' ) )
             ->joinInner( array( 'table2' => 'db2.table2' ), 'table2.field1 = table1.field1', array() );
$result = $select->query->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```

Edit: $db definition sourced from http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Where did you define $db here? Could you please give full example?

Comment: `$db` is the adaptor. It could equally be the table instance. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I appreciate your help! But, I am getting the following error.

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'XXX\\Model\\Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found.

I googled and tried to add the following. But, I am still getting the same error. Please help!

require_once 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php';

or

require_once 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Pdo.php';

or

require_once 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Mysql.php';

or

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

Comment: I am assuming this code will work in zend framework 1.x not in zend framework 2.x.