# unable to fetch record using join zend framework 2 using table gateway

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Here is my function, when I call it the following error occurs:

**Since this object was created with a table and/or schema in the constructor, it is read only**

```
public function getImpressionLeft($AvailableCampaigns){
    $result = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use ($AvailableCampaigns){
        $select->from(array('a'=>'CampaignSettings'));
        $select->columns(array(
            'a.CampaignID',
            'MaxImpression'=>new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('a.MaxImpression - b.TotalImpression'),
            'MaxClick'=> new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('a.MaxClick - b.TotalClicks'), 
            ))->join(array('b'=>'ImpressionCount'),'a.CampaignID = b.CampaignID',Select::JOIN_LEFT)
            ->where(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\In('a.CampaignID',$AvailableCampaigns));
    });
    return $result->getDataSource();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your closure too soon, I'm surprised you didn't get a parse error. You may never get to die instruction.

```
public function getImpressionLeft($AvailableCampaigns){
        $result = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use ($AvailableCampaigns){
            $select->from(array('a'=>'CampaignSettings'));
            $select->columns(array(
                'a.CampaignID',
                'MaxImpression'=>new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('a.MaxImpression - b.TotalImpression'),
                'MaxClick'=> new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('a.MaxClick - b.TotalClicks'), 
                ))->join(array('b'=>'ImpressionCount','a.CampaignID = b.CampaignID',Select::JOIN_LEFT))
                ->where(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\In('a.CampaignID',$AvailableCampaigns));
        });
        return $result->getDataSource();
    }
```

another point is that $result is a ResultSet object, so you can iterate it in a foreach to read each row, you could try returning `$result` instead of `$result->getDataSource();`

Comment: thanks for your reply, sorry i post wrong code . i have edited it

Comment: @SadiqGaur just edited mine too, as the result of TableGateway::select() is a ResultSet

Comment: not getting any thing no resultset,only the errro is appear  "Since this object was created with a table and/or schema in the constructor, it is read only"

Comment: Actually, there is another post that might help you [TableGateway with multiple FROM tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354802/tablegateway-with-multiple-from-tables). Basic gateway seems to be bound to one table, the post show you an exemple to exends a new gateway from AbstractTableGateway