# Use a regex match as an array pointer

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I want to replace some numbers in a string with the content of the array in the position which this number points to.

For example, replace *"Hello 1 you are great"*, with *"Hello myarray[1] you are great"*

I was doing the next: `preg_replace('/(\d+)/','VALUE: ' . $array[$1],$string);`

But it does not work. How could I do it?

Comment: Do your actual use cases need regexes?

Comment: Why are you doing this? It sounds like you are building some sort of template system. It kinda sounds like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Afaik the `$1` is only replaced in *string* values where it literally appears (not sure how PHP does it with its inline variables). Try [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: @Nanne hmmm... it was funny, but this is not really and XY problem. I would say it is an **XYZ** one, because I need to solve X, and I am using method Y, but in order to make my question look more simple, I imagine a situation Z. I need to replace some concrete Ids in a string with a string which contains data from a database, but are already in an array. I could use a callback function instead but... isn't there any other more direct solution?. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a callback.

```
<?php
$str = 'Hello, 1!';
$replacements = array(
    1 => 'world'
);
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+)/', function($matches) use($replacements) {
    if (array_key_exists($matches[0], $replacements)) {
        return $replacements[$matches[0]];
    } else {
        return $matches[0];
    }
}, $str);
var_dump($str); // 'Hello, world!'
```

Since you are using a callback, in the event that you actually want to use a number, you might want to encode your strings as `{1}` or something instead of `1`. You can use a modified match pattern:

```
<?php
// added braces to match
$str = 'Hello, {1}!';
$replacements = array(
    1 => 'world'
);

// added braces to regex
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\{(\d+)\}/', function($matches) use($replacements) {
    if (array_key_exists($matches[1], $replacements)) {
        return $replacements[$matches[1]];
    } else {
        // leave string as-is, with braces
        return $matches[0];
    }
}, $str);
var_dump($str); // 'Hello, world!'
```

However, if you are always matching known strings, you may want to use [@ChrisCooney's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15070805/344643) because it offers less opportunity to screw up the logic.

Comment: Thank you, just had to search for the **use identifier**. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier-should-a-sane-programmer-us

Comment: `trim($matches[0], '{}');` - uh? Shouldn't you just use the appropriate capturing groups, i.e. `/\{(\d+)\}/`?

Comment: @Bergi You are correct. I had thought for some reason the callback should return the replacement for the capture group only, but that of course makes no sense if there are multiple capture groups. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is perfectly fine. I managed it this way:

```
    $val = "Chris is 0";
    // Initialise with index.
    $adj = array("Fun", "Awesome", "Stupid");
    // Create array of replacements.
    $pattern = '!\d+!';
    // Create regular expression.
    preg_match($pattern, $val, $matches);
    // Get matches with the regular expression.
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $adj[$matches[0]], $val);
    // Replace number with first match found.
```

Just offering another solution to the problem :)

Comment: Thank you Chris... this is great too ;) Thanks!

Comment: I'll use the other one because not all numbers exist as array keys, but thanks for sharing intelligence ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Hello 1 you are great";
$replacements = array(1 => 'I think');

preg_match('/\s(\d)\s/', $string, $matches);

foreach($matches as $key => $match) {
  // skip full pattern match
  if(!$key) {
    continue;
  }
  $string = str_replace($match, $replacements[$match], $string);
}
```

Comment: This loses most of the flexibility in using a regex. What if you actually wanted to replace a regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array( 2 => '**', 3 => '***');
$string = 'lets test for number 2 and see 3 the result';
echo preg_replace_callback('/(\d+)/', 'replaceNumber', $string);

function replaceNumber($matches){
 global $array;
 return $array[$matches[0]];
}
?>
```

output

```
lets test for number ** and see *** the result
```