# Variable is null in PHP closure

Tags: php

The variable `$user` is null in this closure function.  I don't understand why.

**Routes.php**

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/classes/user.php');
$user = User::getInstance(); // returns a $_SESSION user or a new User()
```

**This does not work**

```
$app->group('/user', function () use ($app, $user) {

    $app->post('/activate', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
        $parsedBody = $request->getParsedBody();
        $result = $user->activate($parsedBody); // error user is null
        return $response->withJson($result);
    });
});
```

**This does**

```
$app->group('/user', function () use ($app) {

    $app->post('/activate', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
        $parsedBody = $request->getParsedBody();
        $user = User::getInstance();
        $result = $user->activate($parsedBody);
        return $response->withJson($result);
    });
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621297/php-closures-scoping-of-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit that variable into your function.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php - #3

```
$app->group('/user', function () use ($app, $user) {

    $app->post('/activate', function(Request $request, Response $response) use ($user) {
        $parsedBody = $request->getParsedBody();
        $result = $user->activate($parsedBody); // now it shouldn't
        return $response->withJson($result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah.. I really hate that. Is there any way to do it less strict?