# Pass parameters to Symfony's $cache->get()

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cache

I am afraid I have a beginners PHP question. I am using Symfony's Cache component. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html

I am calling the cache object inside of a function which receives 2 arguments ($url, $params).

```
class MainController extends AbstractController {
    public function do($url, $params) {
        $cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
        return $cache->get('myCacheName', function (ItemInterface $c) {
            global $url;
            var_dump($url); // ---> null !!!!
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, that I cannot access the function arguments inside of the cache method call. $url and $params is null.
Of course I could use public class variables in class MainController to send the variables back ad forth, but this seems to be a bit clumsy.

Comment: just use `use` in the closure to import the `$url`, ala `->get(arg1, function() use ($url) {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Closures scoping of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621297/php-closures-scoping-of-variables)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PHP a closure does not have access to variables outside of its scope by default, you have to `use` those like so:

```
return $cache->get('myCacheName', function (ItemInterface $c) use ($url) {
    var_dump($url); // ---> no longer null !!!!
}
```