# Deprecated preg_replace in 5.5.3

Tags: php

I am currently re-programming a framework in php and I upgraded our development server to php 5.5.3. When I fire up the webbrowser, it returns the following error:

```
[19-Oct-2013 16:54:05 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Deprecated:  preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fw/lib/lang.php on line 57
```

And line 57 is;

```
$response = preg_replace('/\{'.$find.'(:(.*))?\}/Ue', 'str_replace("{value}", "\\2", $replace)', $response);
```

I am really horrible at reading these php documentation, I am a beginner and simply changing `preg_replace()` by `preg_replace_callback()` is too good to be true. A co-worker told me it had to be something like $value[1] but that didn't work eather.

Is there a simple solution, am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [the page about modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), giving you more detail about why it is deprecated, and what that means exactly.

Basically the reason is that the `/e` modifier causes a string to be evaluated as PHP code, as if `eval` was called. Using `preg_replace_callback` instead, which allows you to pass it an *actual* PHP function is indeed the way to go.

If you replace the string-code (second parameter) by an anonymous function, your code should then look something like this:

```
$response = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\{'.$find.'(:(.*))?\}/U', 
    function($m) use ($replace) {
      return str_replace($m, "\\2", $replace);
    } , 
    $response);
```

The keyword `use` makes sure that the anonymous function can use the `$replace` variable which should be defined in the calling scope. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier-should-a-sane-programmer-us).

Comment: Note that you can also send [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), as shown in the linked articles.

Comment: I never heard about the [`use` keyword](http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/04/07/php-use-keyword.html). Every day is a learning day!

Comment: Thank you everybody for your reactions. After I changed the string-code by an anonymous function, I get the following error: `PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Closure could not be converted to string`. I think I need to implement the _callback function. Oh and did I forgot to mention that this code is inside a `foreach($key as $find=>$replace)` loop? Maybe this error has to do something with that? I am not sure.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to actually use `preg_replace_callback`. I still called `preg_replace` in my answer, causing PHP to try to convert the function to a string. I assume you copied that and also overlooked my mistake. I've updated the code example.