# Fat free framework: DB query - non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fat-free-framework

We are following the get started tutorial on [github](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree#databases), all went well but we are stranded on the DB connection.

We have created the $db object:

```
    $db=new DB\SQL(
    'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=liselore',
    'jow',
    ''
);
```

And we have set up a controller:

```
$f3->route('GET /',
function($f3) {

    $f3->set('result',$db->exec('SELECT achternaam FROM test1'));

    $template = new Template;
    echo $template->render('views/homepage.html');

    }
);

$f3->run();
```

However, we get this error:

```
Internal Server Error

Fatal error: Call to a member function exec() on a non-object

• fatfree-master/index.php:32
```

I think the error relates to the $db object that is not set. However, we do have php-pdo set, i just checked via phpinfo().

Any help would be great, thx...

Comment: try adding `global $db;` after this line `function($f3) {` - you have a scope issue

Comment: Thx for your answer, but all variables set using the $f3->set method are global, see: https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree#framework-variables

Comment: We are using the exact same code as the examples on the tutorial: https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree#databases

Comment: You're using a closure, you need to use `function($f3) use ($db) {`

Comment: Strange, if i move the new db/sql object creation to 'inside the function' then it all works... any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Liselore you need to read up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) which means the `$db` variable is no longer in [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). You need to use the [`use` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier-should-a-sane-programmer-us) to tell PHP to allow the use of the variable from the parent scope.

```
$f3->route('GET /', function($f3) use ($db) {
    $f3->set('result', $db->exec('SELECT achternaam FROM test1'));

    $template = new Template;
    echo $template->render('views/homepage.html');
});

$f3->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

You said it already:

> all variables set using the $f3->set method are global

and yes, it's a common practise to save such objects in those framework vars. So just try

```
$f3->set('DB', $db=new DB\SQL('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=liselore','jow',''));
```

and use this everywhere else:

```
$f3->set('result',$f3->get('DB')->exec('SELECT achternaam FROM test1'));
```