# What is the advantage of using the use function in PHP?

Tags: php, closures

If write my callback-function this way ...

```
$direction = 'asc';      
$compare = function ($a, $b) use ($direction) {
...
```

... then the script shows the same behaviour as with this:

```
$direction = 'asc';      
$compare = function ($a, $b, $direction = 'asc') {
...
```

In both cases the variable is passed by value.
So, what's the advantage of using the use-function instead of passing the variable via standard function-parameter?

Comment: that is PHP's way to express a closure. [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1065197/2412895) and search up what `closure` means if you don't understand this concept.

Comment: Try changing the first `$direction` variable in your second example to see how it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What is `use`?

`use` means to inherit variables or values from current scope. Parameter can be given from anywhere, but `use`d variable can exist only under certain circumstances. So you might not be able to use closure outside a scope, where `use`d variable is not set:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$fn = function($x)use($y){
    var_dump($x, $y);
};

$fn(1);
?>
```

Shows:

```
Notice:  Undefined variable: y in script.php on line 4
int(1)
NULL
```

However, you can use parametrized closure without such scope-dependecy:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$fn = function($x, $y = null){
    var_dump($x, $y);
};

$fn(1);
?>
```

**See related question:** *[In PHP 5.3.0, what is the function "use" identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier)*.

### What's an advantage?

One of the main use cases of `use` construct is using closures as a callback for other functions (methods). In this case you must follow fixed number of function parameters. So the only way to pass extra parameters (variables) to a callback is `use` construct.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$notWannaSeeThere = 15;
$array  = [ 1, 15, 5, 45 ];
$filter = function($value) use ($notWannaSeeThere){
    return $value !== $notWannaSeeThere;
};

print_r(array_filter($array, $filter));
?>
```

Shows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 45
)
```

In this example, `$filter` closure is used by `array_filter()` and called with only one argument - array element value (and we *"can not"* force it to use additional arguments). Still, we can pass there additionl variables, which availible in parent scope.

**Reference:** [`anonymous functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

> Inheriting variables from the parent scope is not the same as using
>   global variables.

Comment: "One of the main use cases of use construct is using closures as a callback for other functions (methods). In this case you must follow fixed number of function parameters. So the only way to pass extra parameters (variables) to a callback is use construct." Great! That has answered it perfectly. If I use the PHP usort-function (http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) a callback-function with EXACT 2 parameters is expected. With the use-keyword I can provide the claimed callback AND passing additional parameters. Many thanks. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
$compare = function ($a, $b, $direction = 'asc') { ... };
```

This is a normal function which accepts 3 parameters, the last of which is optional. It needs to be called like:

```
$compare('foo', 'bar', 'desc');
```

Here:

```
$direction = 'asc';      
$compare = function ($a, $b, $direction = 'asc') { ... };
```

The two `$direction` variables have absolutely nothing to do with each other.

If you do:

```
usort($array, $compare)
```

then `usort` will only ever call `$compare` with *two* arguments, it will never ever pass the third argument which will always remain at its default value `asc`.

```
$direction = 'asc';      
$compare = function ($a, $b) use ($direction) { ... };
```

Here the `$direction` variable is actually included in the function.

```
$direction = 'asc';  -----------------+
                                      |
$compare = function ($a, $b) use ($direction) {
                                      |
    echo $direction;  <-------------- +
};
```

You are extending the scope of the variable into the function. That's what `use` does. Also see [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/476).