# Laravel 4: query builder advanced where

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, query-builder

I am trying to do a function for auto generating query with advanced where for search function.

Here is my example code:

```
$query->where(function($thisquery){
    $datacolumn = DB::select('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.mysql_real_escape_string($tablename));
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($datacolumn);$i++){
        $field = $datacolumn[$i]->Field;
        $thisquery->orWhere($field,'like','%'.$keyword.'%');
    }
});
```

The problem is how can I pass variables into the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP 5.3.0, what is the function "use" identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the use keyword

```
$query->where(function($thisquery) use ($yourVariable, $yourVariable2) {

});
```