# Remove array elements that are less than X

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays:

```
$arr1 = array(5, 3, 9, 11, 6, 15);
$arr2 = array(11, 20, 1, 3, 8);
```

Now I need to loop through `$arr1` and find the largest number that is less than `X`:

```
foreach($arr1 as $x) {
   //need element that is MAX in $arr2 but is less than $x
}
```

so for example for the first run when `$x = 5`, maximum in `$arr2` is **3** that is less than **5**.

Is it possible to do this without having nested loop? I do not want to loop through `$arr2`. I tried using `array_filter` but didnt really work. Maybe I used it wrong.

This is what I tried with `array_filter`:

```
$results = array();
foreach($arr1 as $x) {
   $max = max(array_filter($arr2, function ($x) { return $x < $y; }));

   $results[$x] = $max;
}
```

The result should be this:

```
5  => 3, 
3  => 1, 
9  => 8, 
11 => 8, 
6  => 3, 
15 => 11
```

Comment: `array_reduce` would make more sense than `array_filter`.  However, what if *none* of the elements are less than `$x`?

Comment: if none are less than $x then return empty array or false

Comment: Shouldn't the results be [3, 1, 8, 8, 3, 11]?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is with the use of the lambda - PHP does *not* automatically capture variables in the enclosing scope. (The official [Anonymous Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) is a bit sparse on the topic, so see  [In PHP 5.3.0, what is the function "use" identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier) as well.)

Compare the original, which returns an empty array as it is effectively `$x < undefined`

```
$arr2 = array(11, 20, 1, 3, 8);
$y = 5;
var_dump(array_filter($arr2, function ($x) { return $x < $y; }));
```

with the following that employs the `use` syntax to bind the variable in the function

```
$arr2 = array(11, 20, 1, 3, 8);
$y = 5;
var_dump(array_filter($arr2, function ($x) use ($y) { return $x < $y; }));
```

(Also, in the original code there was no $y variable at all, whoops!)

Comment: +1 For not writing out the exact code needed but for providing the working logic that will solve the problem

Comment: Thank you. this seems to be working. One question I am not sure what lambda means for PHP can you please explain how the `use` works and in which case this would not work?

Comment: @GGio [Lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_(programming)) is another name for "anonymous function", roughly speaking.

Comment: @user2864740 yea I got that part and read docs for it but still doesnt seem to get the `use` part. So `use($y)` the `$y` part if reference to the `$y = 5`?

Comment: @GGio If you want to access (the non-global) $y inside the function, yes. The documentation is a bit .. uhh, shallow there. [On PHP 5.3, Lambda Functions, and Closures](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/17/on-php-5-3-lambda-functions-and-closures) goes into it in a bit more depth.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a method that uses [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-map.php) to return the values that are lower than your maximum variable, then uses [`max()`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.max.php) to return the highest (as in your example).

In this example I've used `$var` as a [variable by reference (the `&`)](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.references.pass.php), so that it can be used by the `get_highest()` callback function which is accessing it as a global variable.

```
function get_highest($x) {
    global $var;
    return $x < $var ? $x : 0;
}

$results = array();    
foreach($arr1 as &$var) {
    $results[$var] = max(array_map('get_highest', $arr2));
}
```

## Without using global variables

You can modify this if you don't want to use global variables by passing in an array of parameters to `array_map()`. It's a little strange the way it works, because the parameter array needs to be the same length as the original array, so I've used [`array_fill()`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to fill it up to the required length with the current value, so the callback function can use it to compare:

```
function get_highest($x, $y) {
    return $x < $y ? $x : 0;
}

$results = array();    
foreach($arr1 as $var) {
    $max = array_fill(0, count($arr2), $var);
    $results[$var] = max(array_map('get_highest', $arr2, $max));
}
```

Comment: I dont think I want to use `global` anywhere in my code

Answer (score 2):

Any solution that *reuses/resets* `arr2` will be of quadratic complexity, meaning that if you have an arr1 of size N and an arr2 of size M, you'll be doing around N*M operations.

Plus function calls and parameter passing in case of lambda functions.

A better strategy if N and M are very large is to sort both arrays (complexity is N log N + M log M), then use the same strategy as merge sort to loop through the arrays, saving their state. This will execute in at most N+M operations instead of N*M, making the overall complexity [linearithmic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linearithmic_time).

**The lambda solution is easier to understand, more robust and simpler to maintain**, so unless there's a pressing reason (N and M in the tens of thousands), it is to be preferred. You are trading speed for ease of maintenance; but it is normally a sweet deal.

First you sort both arrays with PHP's array sort functions, and get

```
$arr1 = array(3, 5, 6, 9, 11, 15);
$arr2 = array(1, 3, 8, 11, 20);

$map = array();

$n = count($arr1);
$m = count($arr2);

for ($i = 0, $j = 0, $y = false; $i < $n;) {
    if ($j == $m) {
        $map[$arr1[$i++]] = $y;
    } else {
        if ($arr1[$i] <= $arr2[$j]) {
            $map[$arr1[$i++]] = $y;
        } else {
            $y = $arr2[$j++];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is using nested loop, is there a way without using inner loop?

Comment: this version only uses a single loop, still running in N+M (plus the linearithmic cost of sorting, not included in the code).