# How do I pass a array as a param for a Yii2 gridview column

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to pass `$arr_judete_v2` as a param to a callback function in a gridview and it does not work;

`$model['county_id']` returns a number

`$arr_judete_v2[1]['nume']` returns a name

my issue:

```
[
                    'attribute' => 'county_id',
                    'label' => Yii::t('diverse', 'Judet'),
                    'content' => function($model, $arr_judete_v2) {
                        return $arr_judete_v2[$model['county_id']]['nume'];
                    },
                ],
```

the entire gridview

```
<?php
    echo GridView::widget([
        'layout' => "{items}",
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            'id',
            [
                'attribute' => 'nume',
                'label' => Yii::t('companie', 'nume'),
            ],
            'cui',
            'email',
            [
                'attribute' => 'county_id',
                'label' => Yii::t('diverse', 'Judet'),
                'content' => function($model, $arr_judete_v2) {
                    return $arr_judete_v2[$model['county_id']]['nume'];
                },
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' => '{update} {delete}',
                'buttons' => [
                    'update' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', ['update', 'id' => $model['id']], [
                                    'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Update'),
                                    'data-pjax' => '0',
                        ]);
                    }
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the source code for \Yii\grid\Column](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/grid/Column.php#L37)

> @var callable This is a callable that will be used to generated the content of each cell.
>     The signature of the function should be the following: `function ($model, $key, $index, $column)`

As [Mihai has correctly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25326726/428543) you can use `use()` to include variables into the function's scope as follows:

```
"content" => function($model, $key, $index, $column) use ($arr_judete_v2) {
    return $arr_judete_v2[$model['county_id']]['nume'];
}
```

Please note that the variables are copied into the function and as such any changes will not affect the variable outside of the function. A better explanation of this is given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304027/428543).

Comment: you can actually use 'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use (list of variables)

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use use (), see how the function is defined for the value of the column.

```
        $invoice_status_data = array('' => 'Select a status') + ArrayHelper::map(InvoiceStatus::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name');
    ........................
            'columns' => [
    ........................
                        [
                            'attribute'=>'Contact.name',
                            'format'=>'raw',
                            'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use ($invoice_status_data) {
.............................
                                    $content .= 
                                        Html::dropDownList('dropdown'. $model->id, '', $invoice_status_data, [
                                            'class' => 'form-control', 
                                            'onchange' => 'javascript: myInvoice.change($(this));', 
                                            'data-href' => Url::toRoute(['invoice/change-status', "Invoice_id"=>$model->id])]);


                                return $content;
                            },
                        ],
```