# Slim Framework -Single class instance for all routes

Tags: php

Is it possible to create single instance of the class, which will be used in all routes. For example I have this code:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim([
        'mode'  => 'development',
        'debug' => true
    ]);
    use App\API;

    $API = new API;

$app->get('/', function () {

    $API->insertMessage();
});

$app->run();
```

At the moment this is not working, I need to put **$`API = new API`** inside get request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You're looking for another (and different) `use` statement:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($API) {
                           ##########    
    $API->insertMessage();
});
```

That should do it for you, it is inheriting variables from the parent scope. See as well: [Anonymous functions (PHP Manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and [In PHP 5.3.0, what is the function “use” identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1065188/367456).

Comment: Yep, this is working. I wanted something more global (only one call) but this will do :). Thanks :)

Comment: This is only one call and if I see your code right, `$API` is in the global scope, too.