# In Laravel, how can I add items to array in controller and then process after response via App::finish()

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control

I am creating an analytics storage process (using elastic search) where I need to add the items to be stored in elastic from my controller. But then I want to wait until after the response has been sent to the user to actually do the processing. I don't want the user to have to wait for this process to complete before getting the server response.

I am planning on running the processing part using:

```
App::finish(function(){
   // DO THE PROCESSING
})
```

I know that this will run after the response has been sent. However, I am not sure how to get the data which has been compiled in a controller (or any class) to be referenced in the App::finish() closure method.

I have tried using `App::singleton()` but there are many instances where I need to be able to continually 'set' the data, I can't just set it once. I guess I am essentially looking for a global variable that I can manipulate but I know that doesn't exist in Laravel.

Another option is to use `Session::push()` and `Session::get()` but right now I have my Session storage using memcached for this app and I would rather not do additional I/O on memcached when I could just be storing the data needed to be saved in temporary memory.

Seems like I just need a simple container to write to and read from which is saved only in memory but I cannot find that in the Laravel docs.

Comment: As far as I know you can't do something after the request has been sent to the client. I think queues are the way to go...

Comment: @lukasgeiter -- hmm seems like `App::finish()` will do the trick. fingers crossed.

Comment: Really? That kind of surprises me... So the only problem is using data you set in the controller in `App::finish()`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter - you are right. When App::finish() runs the rest of the App data appears to be gone. oh well..

Comment: I'll try some things and post and answer if I find something...

Comment: I just did a `sleep(10)` test and the request even took 10 seconds when I put the sleep inside `App::finish`. So I still think it doesn't run after the request. Even though [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle#application-events) say "The finish event is called after the response from your application has been sent back to the client"

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `__destruct()` magic method on whichever controllers you need to do the processing on.

You could also potentially implement it in `BaseController` as well if it should run for all controllers.

Another option would be to use sqlite in memory.  Simply create a new connection

```
    'sqlite_memory' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),
```

Then you can use `DB::connection('sqlite_memory')` to use that connection and store/save whatever you need using the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to the closure using "use".

[In PHP 5.3.0, what is the function "use" identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier)

I ended up using something like this for storing data in the cache after returning the data to the user.

```
App::finish(function($request, $response) use ($id, $json){
    Cache::put('key_'.$id, $json, 1440);
});
```