# How to pass a callback function with parameters for ob_start in PHP?

Tags: php, caching, ob-start

I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/buffer/) on a caching function. I run into a problem of passing the callback function `cache_page()` for `ob_start`. How can I pass `cache_page()` along with two paramters `$mid` and `$path` to `ob_start`, something along the lines of

```
  ob_start("cache_page($mid,$path)");
```

Of course the above won't work. Here's the example code:

```
$mid = $_GET['mid'];

$path = "cacheFile";

define('CACHE_TIME', 12);

function cache_file($p,$m)
{
    return "directory/{$p}/{$m}.html";
}

function cache_display($p,$m)
{
    $file = cache_file($p,$m);

    // check that cache file exists and is not too old
    if(!file_exists($file)) return;

    if(filemtime($file) < time() - CACHE_TIME * 3600) return;

    header('Content-Encoding: gzip');

    // if so, display cache file and stop processing
    echo gzuncompress(file_get_contents($file));

    exit;
}

  // write to cache file
function cache_page($content,$p,$m)
{
  if(false !== ($f = @fopen(cache_file($p,$m), 'w'))) {
      fwrite($f, gzcompress($content)); 
      fclose($f);
  }
  return $content;
}

cache_display($path,$mid);

ob_start("cache_page"); ///// here's the problem
```

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit what the `cache_page`function is supposed to do? I see it requires three arguments but you are only passing two arguments in the `ob_start` call. Likewise, the callback for `ob_start` has to have the signature `string handler ( string $buffer [, int $phase ] )`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [signature of the callback to `ob_start` has to be](http://php.net/ob_start):

```
string handler ( string $buffer [, int $phase ] )
```

Your `cache_page` method has an incompatible signature:

```
cache_page($content, $p, $m)
```

This means you are expecting different arguments (`$p` and `$m`) than `ob_start` will pass to the callback. There is no way to make `ob_start` change this behavior. It will not send `$p` and `$m`.

In the linked tutorial, the cache file name is derived from the request, e.g.

```
function cache_file()
{
    return CACHE_PATH . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

From your code I take you want to define the file path manually. What you can do then is this:

```
$p = 'cache';
$m = 'foo';

ob_start(function($buffer) use ($p, $m) {
    return cache_page($buffer, $p, $m);
});
```

This passes a compatible callback to `ob_start` which will call your `cache_page` function with the output buffer and [closes over `$p` and `$m`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier) into the callback.

Comment: We should be able to up vote explanation and clarity