# PHP - Function inside of a variable

Tags: php

Im currently learning my way around OOP, i have come across something in a project that im researching and im not sure what it does.

I was wondering if anyone could explain it to me in a bit of detail.

There are 2 bits, as follows

```
    $check_up = function($record) {
        return ($record->status == 1);
    };
```

Im completely lost by this as there is no $record variable set in the entire class, so where is it getting 'status' from ...

and the second example is:

```
    $check_up = function($record) use($website) {
        return ($record->check < $website->warning);
    };
```

Any help would be really appreciated to understand this.

Comment: Look up PHP anonymous functions

Comment: Do you habe a `check_up($something)` call somewhere?

Comment: If you say that there is no `$record` variable defined anywhere in the class, then it's a pretty meaningless anonymous function; but without seeing the rest of the class, we don't know

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier. Note that the `$record` variable is only defined in the local scope of the function. That function could be called in the scope of the `$check_up` variable using something like `$check_up($object_that_has_a_status_property);`.

Comment: Thats interesting, quite confusing, but still interesting ... Thanks for putting a name to it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Commented try to read this `anonymous` `function`

`Anonymous` `functions`, also known as closures, allow the creation of functions which have no specified name. They are most useful as the value of `callback` `parameters`, but they have many other uses.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Much appreciated :)