# PHP "use" over additional parameters for closures?

Tags: php, closures

In what situation is using the `use` keyword with a closure more beneficial then just passing along additional parameters to the closure?

Example #1:

```
$myClosure = function($var1, $var2) use ($var3){
//Some code
}
```

Example #2:

```
$myClosure = function($var1, $var2, $var3){
//Some code
}
```

Like all things it probably depends, but I don't see any functional difference between the two.  Can anyone suggest a situation or example where one example would be preferred over the other?

Comment: FWIW, if you don't use `use`, then it's not a closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see any functional difference between the two.

The arguments are provided by the *caller* of the function. If *you* are the caller and can provide all the necessary arguments, then there is basically no difference*.

However, you might be passing the function somewhere else, so you are *not* caller and do *not* control which arguments are passed. This is the situation that closures solve: You can make values available without calling the function.

See also [In PHP 5.3.0, what is the function "use" identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1065188/218196) .

---

*: The variables that are bound through `use` are defined at definition time. So if the value of the variable changes, there will be a difference:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;

$f1 = function($a, $b) use ($c) {
  echo $a, $b, $c;
};

$f2 = function($a, $b, $c) {
  echo $a, $b, $c;
};

$c = 42;

$f1($a, $b); // 1, 2, 3
$f2($a, $b, $c); // 1, 2, 42
```

Comment: Okay, now I get the difference.  I actually read through the link you provided before asking this question, but in the bit about scope I just interpreted that as the scope in the function is different than outside the function which I understand.  I didn't realize the value passed in the `use` clause was passing the value of the variable at the time of declaration rather than at the time of calling.  Reading the answer again, I guess that is what they meant by "early binding".  Thank you for your answer, it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Say you're using a closure with pre-defined parameters, like `preg_replace_callback` for example, and you want to use a variable from other places in your code, you'd use the `use` keyword

```
$myvar = "hello";
$text = "";
$text = preg_replace_callback('/regex/', function($matches) use ($myvar) {
  return $myvar . " " . $matches[1] . "!";
}, $text);
```

It's a great way to use a variable within a closure with pre-defined parameters, which do not have access to variables outside the closure