# laravel ORM relations : using Conditions on With Joins

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5

im trying to join two tables `post` and `comment` using ORM relations,

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->get();
```

how can i use condition on comments when using `with` to join tables?

i can use whereHas like

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    if(isset($_GET['title']))
    $query->where('title', $_GET['title']);
})->get();
```

but when i use `whereHas` i wouldn't get the post without any comment in the result

basically i want to use left join with condition on the right table

Comment: Can you post your desired `Sql` query so we can understand the problem easily..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a closure to `with()` method like this:

```
$posts = Post::with(['comments' => function($q) {
    $q->where('column', '=', 'value'); // Put conditions here
}])->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need use Closures:

```
$title = $_GET['title'];
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) use ($title) {
    if(!empty($title)) {
        $query->where('title', $_GET['title']);
    }
})->get();
```

Reference:

[In PHP 5.3.0, what is the function "use" identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier)