# To replace the <br> with the <n> in php in an array

Tags: php

```
<?php
  $servername="localhost";
  $username="root";
  $password="";
  $dbname="abc";
  $sql=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname)
  $get=mysqli_query($sql,"SELECT * FORM table_name")

  $dta=array();
  while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)){
      array_push($dta,$fetch);
  }

  $dta=preg_replace("/<br>/",'\n',$dta);
  $json=json_encode($dta);
  echo $json;
  exit;
?>
```

I want to replace the data form the data base. Want to replace column values from 
 with

For example:

1. I have some columns like A, B, C
2. Column A has data like `qwe <br> qu`
3. I want the result of column A would be like `qwe <n> qu`

Note: The above small example has more than 20 columns.

Comment: There is also a function called `nl2br()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: i think i doesn't work for  array

Comment: and where to extract the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has so many bugs.

1. `$fetch` holds an array (not a string)
2. `$dta` is then an array of arrays.
3. `preg_replace` works only on strings not arrays.

You have first to fix that issue.

Replace this line

```
array_push($dta,$fetch);
```

with this:

```
//update all columns from the current fetched row
$fetch = array_map(function($a){ 
       return str_replace(['<br/>','<br>','<br />'],"\n",$a);
},$fetch);
//add the data
array_push($dta,$fetch);
```

and remove the `preg_match` line.

What does `['<br/>','<br>','<br />']` in str_replace?

If you have an array as first parameter then each entry will searched an replaced.  In this example we dont really know how `<br>` is written in the code. Can be `<br/> <br> <br />`, so i have added all the cases here.

More infos:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php  use of str_replace

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php  use of array_map

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php use of `function(){}`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304027/4916265  more about `function()use(){}`

Comment: ok replaced the code but the <br> is not replaced with the "\n"

Comment: @banuprakash updated. Please dont only copy&paste, enhance what we give you :-)

Comment: i replaced it in the while loop

Comment: where to write fetch query

Comment: i am new to php

Comment: @banuprakash I updated my question. And if you use mysqli & json you can not be so new to php ;-) One of the best places to get info about functions http://php.net  like http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$dta=preg_replace("/<br>/",'\n',$dta);
```

To:

```
array_walk($dta, function(&$val){
    $val = str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $val);
});
```

& keep in mind:

- For `\n` use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`.
- If the resulted string having new lines will be used in Windows, replace with `\r\n` instead of just `\n`
- There is no need for `preg_replace`, `str_replace` would perfectly fit
- As `$dta` is an array, we have to use `array_walk` or loop in the array.

Comment: $dta = an array. you will have to loop and replace.

Comment: Your callback does not have an input parameter `function(){`, so within the function you have no varaible with the current value. `$dta` does not exists in the function.

Comment: geting  dta is undefined @HossamMagdy

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: dta  in the line 26

Comment: Did you replace the exactly mentioned line as written above ?

Comment: yes,once u replace my totall code with  your anwser please

Comment: yes i replace this line $dta=preg_replace("/<br>/",'\n',$dta);
with your code