# laravel : Not able to pass parameters to trait

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I created a trait in MailTrait.php, the following is my code

```
namespace App\Traits;
use Mail;
trait MailTrait
{

    public function fn_send_mail($arr_recepients, $str_subject, $str_content)
    {
        Mail::send('mail.mailsample', ['content' => $str_content], function($message)
        {
            $message->to($arr_recepients);
            $message->from('abc.org', 'abc');
            $message->subject($str_subject);

        });
        if(Mail:: failures())
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

}
```

from my controller called the function fn_send_mail() and passed parameter as below
`$status = $this->fn_send_mail(['123.gmail.com'],'hai', 'hai');`

i am getting this error
`ErrorException in MailTrait.php line 14: Undefined variable: arr_recepients`
please help me!!

Comment: Read about [use keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier) in anonymous functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd argument to `Mail::send` is a closure, and it doesn't have `$arr_recepients` in scope, nor the subject. You need to use the `use`. Try this

```
Mail::send('mail.mailsample', ['content' => $str_content], function($message) use ($arr_recepients, $str_subject)
    { //...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the `$arr_recepients` to the callback-block

```
Mail::send('mail.mailsample', ['content' => $str_content], function($message) use ($arr_recepients, $str_subject)
{
      $message->to($arr_recepients);
      $message->from('abc.org', 'abc');
      $message->subject($str_subject);
});
```