# How to get the matched substring in preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I remove the first occurrence of a html tag in a string with `preg_replace` as

```
$html = preg_replace('#<p>(.*?)</p>#i', '', $html, 1);
```

How can I save the deleted substring as a new string:

```
$deleted = '<p>...</p>';
```

Comment: DOMDocument::removeChild

Comment: @All Casimir's comment is best practice.  It is most trustworthy to use a html parser to process html strings.  For best results, you should take the time to research and develop a method that leverages his advice.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) which passes the match to a user defined function.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback($re, function ($m) use (&$p) { $p = $m[0]; }, $str, 1);
```

- `$m` any variable name for the matches array where index `0` is the full pattern match
- [`use`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065197/5527985) `(&$p)` any variable name for storing the match (passed by reference).

[See this demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/843606)

Answer (score 0):

to get the substring you can use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
preg_match('#<p>(.*?)</p>#i', $html, $matches);
```

just check the $matches variable it contain what you need.

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
>   $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern,
>   $matches[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will have the text that matched the first captured
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

after that use `preg_replace` to delete the `<p>` tag.

but if you want only to remove the `<p>` tag and keep the substring just `preg_replace` like this :

```
$html = "left <p>substring</p> right";
$html = preg_replace('#</?p>#i', '', $html);

echo $html;
```

output :

```
left substring right
```

Comment: I posted this exact answer but got several downvotes for it.  This site can be infurating at times!

Comment: Yeah for sure, sometimes people are weird :/

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
$result = preg_match('#<p>(.*?)</p>#i', $html);
```

Comment: What question are you answering? `preg_match` returns a boolean, what are you doing after?