# Purpose of PHP use keyword in array_map() function?

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I've the following code of lines in my application.
Can anybody please tell me what is the purpose of **`use`** keyword in the following `array_map()` function?

```
array_map( function($record) use ($edit_form, $otherfields, $otherfields_keys)
{
    User::parseData($record, $edit_form['metadata']);

    if (isset($otherfields[$record['user_id']])) {
        return $record + $otherfields[$record['user_id']];
    }

    return $record + $otherfields_keys;

}, $records);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In PHP 5.3.0, what is the function "use" identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The callback passed to `array_map()` doesn't have access to outside variables so they must be passed using `use`.

You can read more about anonymous functions in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).