# Avoiding php global variables in function by sending them as parameters

Tags: php, function, global-variables

I'm pretty new to php and I've read many times "avoid global variables" but I've not understood whether I have to follow this advice everytime or not.

I need some values (they are stored into two variables) into a function and I could put both variables as parameters:

```
$GVar1 = array(...); //This is a multidimensional array (over 80.000 chars in declaration)
$GVar2 = array(...);

$Result = DoMyStuff('BasicValue', $GVar1, $GVar2);

function DoMyStuff ($BasicParameter, $GV1, GV2){
    //Do stuff
}
```

or declare variables as global into the function:

```
$GVar1 = array(...);
$GVar2 = array(...);

$Result = DoMyStuff('BasicValue');

function DoMyStuff ($BasicParameter){
    global $GVar1;
    global $GVar2;
    //Do stuff
}
```

I would like to understand if the first way is really better .. and why?

Comment: Have you done any research before asking? This is a very broad question that's been addressed *many* times, and isn't at all specific to PHP.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've searched but I haven't find anything peculiar. A link could be useful ;)

Comment: Might be worth looking up [Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) ...

Comment: Yes the first way is better. Among other things, it encapsulates all of its requirements into the function definition. Think about somebody else reading your code. In the first case, they will clearly understand what they have to pass in. In the second case, they don't necessarily have any idea that they need to pass a parameter *and* set up some global variables with a particular name.

Comment: @CD001 Thanks! Very useful link. I'm starting to understand (I'm a self-taught)

Comment: @AlexHowansky It's better even if I need to send a very big array? I mean over 80.000 chars (It's big for me; I don't know if is it the same for a server)

Comment: And now ponder about ... `$callback = function($BasicParameter) use ($GVar1, $GVar2) { };` ... :)

Comment: @IncredibleHat Sorry, I didn't understand. I need more info about your code. Remember: I'm not a pro

Comment: Just a different way of passing a seemingly global variable into a function. Making code even more confusing to someone who comes along later ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier

Comment: @genespos IncredibleHat's example there is an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) ... useful in certain cases but probably not something you'll use regularly, especially when you're just starting out in PHP...

Comment: I would say parameter should be pass by reference. because if you update `$GVar1` and `$GVar2` values inside the function it will not updated the outside arrays. you may need to use somewhere else these arrays.