# Cannot get object name value outside Excel::load()

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am creating a contacts directory. I have a contact group with contact numbers in it. I am using this composer package `"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"`. I can save the contact group in my `contact_groups` table but my code cannot get the id of the newly created contact group.

This is my code.

```
$group = new ContactGroup();
$group->company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
$group->group_name = $request['group_name'];
     if ($group->save()) {
        Excel::load($request->file('file')->getRealPath(), function ($reader) {
            foreach ($reader->toArray() as $key => $row) {
               $contact = new Contact();
               $contact->group_id = $group->id;
               $contact->company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
               $contact->contact_name = $row['contact_name'];
               $contact->contact_number = $row['contact_number'];
               $contact->save();
             }
        });
        Session::flash('success','New contact group has been created!');
        return back();
     }
```

I am getting an error saying `Undefined variable: group`

and it is pointing to this line `$contact->group_id = $group->id;`

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass `$group` inside the anonymous function using `use` keyword.

`function ($reader) use ($group) {`.

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-what-is-a-closure-and-why-does-it-use-the-use-identifier)

Answer (score 1):

change your code inside of `if` condition, so that it looks like the following:

```
Excel::load($request->file('file')->getRealPath(), function ($reader) use ($group) {
            foreach ($reader->toArray() as $key => $row) {
               $contact = new Contact();
               $contact->group_id = $group->id;
               $contact->company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
               $contact->contact_name = $row['contact_name'];
               $contact->contact_number = $row['contact_number'];
               $contact->save();
             }
        });
```