# why won't regular functions support the `use` keyword for importing variables from outside

Tags: php

One way to bring an outside variable inside a scope is by using the `use` keyword in PHP.

My question is, why can we only do it on a closure/anonymous function and not on a regular function:

```
$func = function() use ($globalVar) {}; // this works

function func() use ($globalVar) {} // this  won't work. Why?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-what-is-a-closure-and-why-does-it-use-the-use-identifier

Comment: Because you can use `global $globalVar` or `$GLOBALS['globalVar']`

Comment: it works see this example `<?php $add = 'World'; $arr = ['Hello']; echo array_map(function($in) use ($add) {return $in . $add;}, $arr)[0]; ?>` displays `HelloWorld` and the function has an access to `$add`. The second function in your example isn't a regular function but also an anonymous function that uses closure. In the second example you simply don't use the function. Hence the lack of any effect.