# How to attach file in storage to mail - laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I've tried this to attach file in storage to a mail:

```php
$attachments = OnlineReply::where('ContactNo', $ContactNo)->first() ; 
$HOR_IMG= '/home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/public/storage/'.$attachments['HOR_IMG'];
$NIC_IMG= '/home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/public/storage/'.$attachments['NIC_IMG'];

//dd($HOR_IMG,$NIC_IMG);         

Mail::send('mail.CRepliesSend',$data, function($message) use ($to_name,$to_email)
{   $message->to($to_email)->subject('reply for your add on mangala sewa'); 
    $message->attach($HOR_IMG);
    $message->attach($NIC_IMG);
});
```

But I get this result:

> ErrorException
>   Undefined variable: HOR_IMG

WHat is wrong, and how could I make this work ?

Comment: `use ($to_name,$to_email)` should also contains `$HOR_IMG, $NIC_IMG` because they are outside of the scope

Comment: can you help me example , i need to attach file , that variable is the path of attachment

Comment: With the information you provided I cannot help you more than what I already commented. In short replace `use ($to_name,$to_email)
` with `use ($to_name, $to_email, $HOR_IMG, $NIC_IMG)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgotten to add the `$HOR_IMG` & `$NIC_IMG` to the `use` of the closure passed to `Mail::send`, below the updated code.

```
$attachments = OnlineReply::where('ContactNo', $ContactNo)->first() ; 
$HOR_IMG= '/home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/public/storage/'.$attachments['HOR_IMG'];
$NIC_IMG= '/home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/public/storage/'.$attachments['NIC_IMG'];

//dd($HOR_IMG,$NIC_IMG);         

Mail::send('mail.CRepliesSend',$data, function($message) use ($to_name,$to_email,$HOR_IMG,$NIC_IMG)
{   $message->to($to_email)->subject('reply for your add on mangala sewa'); 
    $message->attach($HOR_IMG);
    $message->attach($NIC_IMG);
});
```

---

In case it's not clear what `use` does I'd like to redirect you to this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065197/1580028.