# ErrorException: Undefined variable: request in file

Tags: php, laravel

Error **ErrorException: Undefined variable: request in file** always appears, even though I have defined it as below

```
public function postlog_show(Request $request)
    {
        $log = $request->log;
        $userlocation = Auth::user()->location;
        $postlocations = Postlocation::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('location', $userlocation)
                ->whereHas('postlognya', function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->where('log', 'like', '%' . $request->log . '%');
                })
        ->get();

        return view('front.postlog2')
            ->with('postlocations', $postlocations)
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will have to `use` `$request` variable in `whereHas` function, like I've shown

```
public function postlog_show(Request $request)
{
    $log = $request->log;
    $userlocation = Auth::user()->location;
    $postlocations = Postlocation::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('location', $userlocation)
            ->whereHas('postlognya', function (Builder $query) use($request){
                $query->where('log', 'like', '%' . $request->log . '%');
            })
    ->get();

    return view('front.postlog2')
        ->with('postlocations', $postlocations)
    ;
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Also, if you are interested to know why, have a read at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-what-is-a-closure-and-why-does-it-use-the-use-identifier.