# How to validate a unique field for uniqueness under a category in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I have two tables **categories** and **sub_categories**.
I want to validate the **name** field of **subcategories** table to be unique under the same category.

sub_category table fields

> id  |   name |  category_id

Using Laravel validation I am using this code but getting error messsage ErrorException Undefined **variable: request**

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

       $validatedData = $request->validate([
          'category_id' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
          'name' => [
            'required', 'max:255',
            Rule::unique('sub_categories')->ignore($id)->where(function($query){
              return $query->where('category_id',$request->category_id);
            })
          ],

      ]);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ErrorException: Undefined variable: request in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890456/errorexception-undefined-variable-request-in-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `use($request)`  to pass $request instance inside where condition

```php
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'category_id' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
            'name' => [
                'required', 'max:255',
                Rule::unique('sub_categories')->ignore($id)->where(function ($query) use($request) {
                    return $query->where('category_id', $request->category_id);
                }),
            ],

        ]);
    }
```

Comment: I don't want unique validation to fail if the name is under different category...ie  if sub_category  have same name but different category_id

Answer (score -1):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
        request()->validate([
            'category_id' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
            'name'=> 'required|Max:255|unique:sub_categories,name,'. $id.',id'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it answers the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.