# finding matching and corresponding values in 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

first array of total transactions (haystack):

```
[0] => Array (
    [transaction_id] => 62369600431
    [invoice_number] => 37161
    )
[1] => Array (
    [transaction_id] => 62369595048
    [invoice_number] => 37346
    )
[2] => Array (
    [transaction_id] => 62369537530
    [invoice_number] => 38064
    )
```

Second array of select orders (needle):

```
[0] => Array (
    [invoice_number] => 37161
    )
[1] => Array (
    [invoice_number] => 37346
    )
```

My goal is to create a third array that finds all transaction_id from the first array that have a match of order_id from the second.

I have tried array_merge and array_intersect both unsuccessfully (because I don't fully understand how to use them obviously.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and get all the invoice_numbers to check for using example [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

Then in the filter, check if the number occurs in the invoice_numbers using [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
$array1 = [
    [
        "transaction_id" => 62369600431,
        "invoice_number" => 37161
    ],
    [
        "transaction_id" => 62369595048,
        "invoice_number" => 37346
    ],
    [
        "transaction_id" => 62369600431,
        "invoice_number" => 38064
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    [
        "invoice_number" => 37161
    ],
    [
        "invoice_number" => 37346
    ]
];

$invoiceNumbers = array_column($array2, "invoice_number");
$result = array_filter($array1, function($x) use ($invoiceNumbers) {
   return in_array($x["invoice_number"], $invoiceNumbers);
});

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 62369600431
            [invoice_number] => 37161
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [transaction_id] => 62369595048
            [invoice_number] => 37346
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/486fu)

Comment: Thanks this works great. Can you explain to me the portion of the callback in array_filter. I am not really understanding the function($x) use ($invoiceNumbers).

Comment: array_filter iterates over all the values in the array and passes each value to the callback. To use in_array, the callback needs the array with invoice numbers and that is where `use` is for. This page can be helpful explaining how that works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-what-is-a-closure-and-why-does-it-use-the-use-identifier