# How to pass a value to an add_action() closure?

Tags: php, elementor

This is my code

```
<?php
$usersfollowing=1;
echo($usersfollowing);

            add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'author', '1' );
} );
?>
```

It is working fine when I give value '1' after the 'author'. I want to use $usersfollowing to pass value as 1. When I do `$query->set( 'author', $usersfollowing )` it does not work.

I want to use $usersfollowing to pass variable value.

Comment: I suspect you need `function($query) use ($usersfollowing) {` to bring the variable into local function scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$usersfollowing = 1;
echo($usersfollowing);

add_action('elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function ($query) use ($usersfollowing) {
    $query->set('author', $usersfollowing);
});
```

As pointed out in the comments by Nico Haase:
[In PHP, what is a closure and why does it use the "use" identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-what-is-a-closure-and-why-does-it-use-the-use-identifier)