# Yii2 - how to refer to main model in a gii(ant) generated view, under a relations tab?

Tags: yii2

I have a standard giiant generated view where the main model **$model** is present. First part of the View is a Detailview widget:

```
<?=
DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
```

So far clear. Then comes relations tabs (or blocks):

```
<?php $this->beginBlock('relatedmodels');
echo GridView::widget(['dataProvider' => new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $model->getRelatedmodels()]),
...
'columns' => [
    [
        'attribute' => 'calculated',
        'value' => function ($relatedmodel) {return $relatedmodel->getCalculated($model->id);},
    ],
```

This gives of course an error

> Undefined variable: model

Controller is also standard giiant generated:

```
public function actionView($id) {
    \Yii::$app->session['__crudReturnUrl'] = Url::previous();
    Url::remember();
    Tabs::rememberActiveState();

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

How can I pass the main model id to the function `getCalculated()` ? Or how to initialise $model into the anonymous function (is it possible at all) ? Can you please point me to the right direction ?

Comment: add controller action  code also.

Comment: `'value' => function ($relatedmodel)  use ($model) {return $relatedmodel->getCalculated($model->id);},`

Comment: Wow, thank you, it's working flawlessly. Is there some kind of documentation about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Anonymous function - use()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and [what is a closure and why does it use the “use” identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-what-is-a-closure-and-why-does-it-use-the-use-identifier)

```
$this->beginBlock('relatedmodels');
<?= GridView::widget(['dataProvider' => new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $model->getRelatedmodels()]),
...
'columns' => [
    [
        'attribute' => 'calculated',
        'value' => function ($relatedmodel) use ($model) {return $relatedmodel->getCalculated($model->id);},
    ],
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried several different variants but cannot use 2 variables at the same time, e.g. $model and $relatedmodel. Is it a Yii specific thing, or what am I missing?

Comment: I have no idea how I have figured it out, and why it is like this, but this is working: 'value' => function ($mdl) use ($model, $mainmodel) {return $mdl->attr . $model->attr}