# Trying to sort an array of objects using usort in php

Tags: php, usort

I'm working on a WordPress site, trying to sort post tags, which is an array of objects with various members including `slug` and `name`. I've created an array of tag slug strings in priority order, and trying to sort a post's array of tags according to that array's values, with the post's slug as the key. Example:

```
$tagPriorityMap = array(
  "research" => 0,
  "strategy" => 1,
  "naming" => 2,
  "identity" => 3,
  "packaging" => 4,
  "environment" => 5,
  "digital" => 6,
);
function sort_tags($a, $b) {
  if ($tagPriorityMap[$a->slug] == $tagPriorityMap[$b->slug]) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($tagPriorityMap[$a->slug] < $tagPriorityMap[$b->slug]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

If I echo some code inside the sort_tags function, it shows that `$a->slug` is a string like "strategy", but it also shows that `$tagPriorityMap[$a->slug]` returns no value. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Besides making that variable global as the answer shows, you could also just move it inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `$tagPriorityMap` must be declared as a global variable inside the function.
Jut try:

```
function sort_tags($a, $b) {
  global $tagPriorityMap;
  if ($tagPriorityMap[$a->slug] == $tagPriorityMap[$b->slug]) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($tagPriorityMap[$a->slug] < $tagPriorityMap[$b->slug]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

**Added**
Idea provided from [Maik Lowrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14807111/maik-lowrey)

just add the `$tagPriorityMap` as parameter of the function for a global usage

```
function sort_tags($a, $b, $tagPriorityMap) {
  if ($tagPriorityMap[$a->slug] == $tagPriorityMap[$b->slug]) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($tagPriorityMap[$a->slug] < $tagPriorityMap[$b->slug]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Or pass the $tagPriorityMap to the function sort_tags($a, $b, $tagPriorityMap).

Comment: Defining a global is not really the best solution, in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

I really wonder why @Cârnăciov deleted his answer, it was far better than the one that was accepted.
Dumping the priorities in a global is ok for a test, but if you solve all your problems by littering the global namespace you'll soon be in trouble.

You could avoid this with the [`use()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304027/2960823) keyword like Cârnăciov suggested.

But you can simply define your priorities as a static variable directly inside the function. It will behave exactly like a global, except nobody but the comparison function will see it.
The PHP7 [spaceship operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php/31298778#31298778) can also be used to simplify the comparison, it's tailor-made for that:

```
function sort_tags ($a, $b) {
        static $prio = array(
          "research" => 0,
          "strategy" => 1,
          "naming" => 2,
          "identity" => 3,
          "packaging" => 4,
          "environment" => 5,
          "digital" => 6,
        );
        return $prio[$a->slug] <=> $prio[$b->slug];
    }
```

Or you can use [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) too. These allow you to emulate the convoluted way JavaScript has handled closures these last 25 years :D
(sorry, just a little joke)

```
$sort_tags = (function () { // this anonymous function closes over "prio"
        $prio = array(      // and returns the actual comparison function
          "research" => 0,
          "strategy" => 1,
          "naming" => 2,
          "identity" => 3,
          "packaging" => 4,
          "environment" => 5,
          "digital" => 6,
        );
        // the comparison function sees "prio" captured in the upper level closure
        return fn ($a, $b) => 
            $prio[$a->slug] <=> $prio[$b->slug]; // handles the -1, 0 and 1 cases in one go
    })(); // immediately invoked function expression, just like in JavaScript
```

A silly example demonstrating that you no longer need a global:

### file `test.php`

```
<?php

function demo () {
    
    $sort_tags = function ($a, $b) {
            static $prio = array(
              "research" => 0,
              "strategy" => 1,
              "naming" => 2,
              "identity" => 3,
              "packaging" => 4,
              "environment" => 5,
              "digital" => 6,
            );
            return $prio[$a->slug] <=> $prio[$b->slug];
    };


    $sample = [
        (object)["slug" => "naming"   , "id" => 1],
        (object)["slug" => "packaging", "id" => 2],
        (object)["slug" => "research" , "id" => 3],
        (object)["slug" => "strategy" , "id" => 4]];

    echo "<br>before usort:<br><br>";
    foreach ($sample as $item) echo $item->slug, " => ", $item->id, "<br>";
    echo "<br>after usort:<br><br>";

    usort ($sample, $sort_tags);

    foreach ($sample as $item) echo $item->slug, " => ", $item->id, "<br>";
}

demo();
?>
```

### browser output

```
before usort:

naming => 1
packaging => 2
research => 3
strategy => 4

after usort:

research => 3
strategy => 4
naming => 1
packaging => 2
```